# Kops cannot edit nodes instance types

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I'm getting the following error when trying to modify the instance types of the worker/master nodes of my k8s cluster.

```
error reading InstanceGroup "nodes": InstanceGroup.kops.k8s.io "nodes" not found
```

I run the following:

```
kops edit ig nodes --name ${NAME}

error reading InstanceGroup "nodes": InstanceGroup.kops.k8s.io "nodes" not found
```

Am I missing something here?

```
$ kops get instancegroups --name ${NAME}
NAME            ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX ZONES
master-us-east-2a   Master  t3.medium   1   1   us-east-2a
nodes-us-east-2a    Node    t3.medium   1   1   us-east-2a
nodes-us-east-2b    Node    t3.medium   1   1   us-east-2b
```

This works.

Maybe Kops has changed recently and they don't group all nodes under the same name anymore as previously?

Comment: Aside from this not being a programming question, the `get ig` list sure does look like it comes back with 3 named IGs, none of which are named `nodes`, thus, `kops edit ig nodes-us-east-2a` is more likely to do what you expect

Comment: I think if you will check [kops ig github docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_get_instancegroups.md) it will be clear. In short in first command you have used `nodes` and in second you skipped it thus you got output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kOps did indeed change recently in that *new* clusters are provisioned with one instance group per availability zone (AZ) instead of having one node IG that spans all AZs.

So in your case, you want to edit both `nodes-us-east-2a` and `nodes-us-east-2b`.

As a bonus comment, I really recommend that you both

- use `kops get -o yaml` to dump the specs and put them under version control
- [template your IG spec](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/operations/cluster_template/) so that you ensure they are consistent.